# XSLT to last level child nodes in xml

Tags: xml, xslt, parent-child, flatten

I'm trying to flatten input nested xml, with child nodes having names as parentnode.childnode

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<queryResponse>
  <Account>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Name>AA</Name>
    <RecordTypeId>1</RecordTypeId>
    <RecordType>
      <Id>1</Id>
      <DeveloperName>A</DeveloperName>
    </RecordType>
  </Account>
  <Account>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Name>BB</Name>
    <RecordTypeId>2</RecordTypeId>
    <RecordType>
      <Id>2</Id>
      <DeveloperName>B</DeveloperName>
    </RecordType>
  </Account>
  </queryResponse>
```

Expected ouptut

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<queryResponse>
  <Account>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Name>AA</Name>
    <RecordTypeId>1</RecordTypeId>
    <RecordType.Id>1</RecordType.Id><RecordType.DeveloperName>A</RecordType.DeveloperName>
  </Account>
  <Account>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Name>BB</Name>
    <RecordTypeId>2</RecordTypeId>
    <RecordType.Id>2</RecordType.Id><RecordType.DeveloperName>B</RecordType.DeveloperName>
  </Account>
  </queryResponse>
```

current XSLT code , looks for nodes (dynamically) which has child and changes the child node names.

```html
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 
       
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>  
        </xsl:copy> 
        
           
    </xsl:template>
   
      <xsl:template match="*/*/*"> 
         <xsl:for-each select="*">
             <xsl:element name="{concat(name(..),'.',name())}"> 
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/> 
         </xsl:element>
         </xsl:for-each>   
         
     </xsl:template> 
       
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And getting the below outputs , where grand child node names are changed but other nodes are not getting copied , could you help me what am i missing

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><queryResponse>
  <Account>
    <RecordType.Id>1</RecordType.Id><RecordType.DeveloperName>A</RecordType.DeveloperName>
  </Account>
  <Account>
    <RecordType.Id>2</RecordType.Id><RecordType.DeveloperName>B</RecordType.DeveloperName>
  </Account>
  </queryResponse>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the for-each select to select the currently matched element(if it doesn't have any child elements) or it's descendant elements:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>  
        </xsl:copy> 
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*/*/*">
        <xsl:for-each select=".[not(*)]|.//*">
            <xsl:element name="{concat(name(..),'.',name())}"> 
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/> 
            </xsl:element>  
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You could eliminate the for-each and use two specialized templates:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>  
        </xsl:copy> 
    </xsl:template>
    <!--If we are at least 3 levels deep and do not have any child elements,
        rename it -->
    <xsl:template match="/*/*//*[not(*)]">
        <xsl:element name="{concat(name(..),'.',name())}"> 
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/> 
        </xsl:element>  
    </xsl:template> 

    <!--If we are at least 3 levels deep and have any child elements,
        keep going-->
    <xsl:template match="/*/*//*[*]">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: it works , but still the parent node of the changed child elements exist.<Account>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Name>A</Name>
    <RecordTypeId>1</RecordTypeId>
    <RecordType>
      <RecordType.Id>1</RecordType.Id>
      <RecordType.DeveloperName>A</RecordType.DeveloperName>
    </RecordType>
  </Account>